# RabbitMQ reque to another consumer

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is it possible to force reque on another consumer in case of message reque ? For example my service wants to process request from queue (where multiple consumers are) and in the middle of processing finds that it has a low local space or whatever. It does not make sense to retry processing on this consumer, but another consumer can still process the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the low-space consumer should simply nACK the message. This means negative acknowledgment. The message will get-requeued and evetually delivered to another consumer. More info here https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-nacks-requeue

Comment: But there is no guarantee that the redelivery will be to a different consumer, unless you `stop()` the listener container on the one that has run out of resources.

Comment: Is there some method for forcing Rabbit to redelivery this particular message to another consumer (other than stopping it) ?

Comment: Aside from consumer remembering the message that it shouldn't consume again, and nACK it next time if it comes, I can't think of anything ATM. But if you are as you wrote running out of disk space, then it's not that you can't process a message but you can't process any messages further (say until you free up disk space) and  you need  to stop consuming all together as Gary suggested